# Interdependent classes in separate files (circular import)

Tags: python, python-2.7, circular-dependency

I have 2 classes (GraphQL type definitions) that depend on each other. I would like to move them to separate files.

As long as they are defined in the same file, no problems.

```
# all_schemas.py

class AuthorSchema(graphene.ObjectType):
    publications = graphene.List(lambda: PublicationSchema)


class PublicationSchema(graphene.ObjectType):
    author = graphene.Field(AuthorSchema)
```

As soon as I put them into separate files, I run into the 'circular import' issue.

author_schema.py

```
from publication_schema import PublicationSchema

class AuthorSchema(graphene.ObjectType):
    publications = graphene.List(lambda: PublicationSchema)
```

publication_schema.py

```
from author_schema import AuthorSchema

class PublicationSchema(graphene.ObjectType):
    author = graphene.Field(AuthorSchema)
```

Here's what the error that I believe to show the circular import issue:

```
from author_schema import AuthorSchema
  File "models/author_schema.py", line 1, in <module>
    from publication_schema import PublicationSchema
  File "models/publication_schema.py", line 2, in <module>
    from author_schema import AuthorSchema
ImportError: cannot import name AuthorSchema
```

**What are my options for solving this issue?**

Some people said that circular imports are bad practice, I don't see why this would be the case here, but I would like to learn why. They also suggest to refactor the code, but I'm wondering how to do that exactly, without ending up with one huge file which contain all interdependent classes.

(Note that I'm using Python 2.7, on google app engine)

Comment: It's a bad practice because, in your case, there is no way to create `PublicationSchema` class structure without knowing what `AutorSchema` is (`PublicationSchema` class attribute `author` depends on it), but you cannot create `AutorSchema` in the first place because its `publications` attribute depends on `PublicationSchema`. This makes the whole structure illogical and there is no way for Python interpreter to know what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks @zwer, what I don't understand is this: the logical concept works fine, as long as everything is defined in the same file. The _only_ thing I'm trying to do is re-organize the code, while the (working) logic stays exactly the same...

Comment: It gets stuck on the import because that's the first command so the interpreter tries to load whatever module you're giving it first. With two inter-related dependencies, when it tries to load the dependency it gets thrown back to the file it came from which causes it not to parse the second file (to avoid infinite loop) and thus fail to load the dependencies. When the classes are in the same file, Python is able to resolve the circular dependency as it first creates pointers to the classes themselves instead of trying to load them first.

Comment: yea, that's the problem I'm describing, and that I'm looking at a solution for:)

Comment: The alternative is to put all classes into one file and that blows up the file indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The standard python trick to avoid circular dependencies,is to avoid them running at import time. Instead of putting. For example, put `from author_schema import AuthorSchema` inside the `PublicationSchema` class, so it does not run at the time this class is imported from `AuthorSchema`. However, this is unstable, the exact point to put them depends on the code and might change as the code changes.

The standard OOP approach is to for a `AuthorInterface`, that the publication imports and the author implements. See *acyclic dependencies principle* and *dependency inversion principle*.

Comment: Is the interface abstraction approach even possible in Python given that it does not support interfaces?

Comment: @JonathanKomar: it does, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Answer (score 1):

The above comment standing, if you really, really have to do this (and you don't!) you can always use delayed import in your `AuthorSchema`:

```
def get_publication_schema():
    from publication_schema import PublicationSchema
    return PublicationSchema

class AuthorSchema(graphene.ObjectType):

    publications = graphene.List(get_publication_schema)
```

The caveat - you still won't be able to execute any of the code that calls `PublicationSchema` from the 'global' space of `autor_schema.py` as both files need to be fully loaded in order to reference one another. But in third-party usage scenario this will work.

Comment: hi @zwer, really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. You're saying "if you really, really have to do this (and you don't!)..." By "do this", I assume you mean "put 2 interdependent classes into separate files" - ok, I don't have to do this, but this is how I'd like to structure my code - or is this an unreasonable goal in your option?

Comment: As @blue_note said above, having interlocking dependencies goes against OOP principles. You can do it via lazy importing, as mentioned above, but then you're technically forcing the language to use your idea of structure than what is perceived as a good OOP approach (a clear dependency tree for starters). Since everything, in the end, turns into a procedural execution, try following the train of execution and you'll understand why Python complains - it's the ambiguity that throws it off the wack.

Comment: And just to be clear, I said that you don't need this more as a suggestion to rethink your structure as there must be a way to achieve your goals without going against the grain of your compiler/interpreter and without sacrificing clear ownership/dependency structure.

Comment: The alternative is to have huge class files. Which also is not good practice.